# How to create javascript function in custom Wordpress plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have create a custom plugin for listing candidate using wp_list_table. Now I have to show all fields information in a popup , on click of href. Below are the step, I am including JavaScript, but it's not working.

1. in my plugin file I included js file as:

   ```
   include WP_CONTENT_DIR."/plugins/candidate_cv_listing/includes.php";
   ```

   calling my js function like this:

   ```
   <a href="#"  onclick ="show_details('.$item['id'].');" >Click here </a>'
   ```
2. in includes.php following code i had written:

   ```
        if( $hook != 'candidate_cv_listing.php' ) 
       return;
      // core
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
      //echo '<script type="text/javascript"     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">   </script>';
   // registering my js file
   wp_register_script('can_list',plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'cand.js');
   wp_enqueue_script('can_list',plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'cand.js');
   }
   add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'candidates_gen_js');
   ?>
   ```
3. now in cand.js file i am writting my js code as::

   ```
   function show_details(id){
     //alert(id);
     datastring = 'id='+id;
     $.ajax({
       url: "<?php echo plugins_url();?>/candidate_cv_listing/list_detail.php", 
       type: "POST",
       data: datastring,
       success: function(result){
         $.fancybox(result);
       }
     });
   }
   ```

Please let me know the correct method of including js to plugin, since my plugin will be used in admin-end and how should I make call to my function. Right now its giving me:

```
ReferenceError: show_details is not defined
```

Comment: thankyou Brett DeWoody, for making my question in more readable form.

Comment: To begin with, 1. I am seeing PHP syntax error in `includes.php`, 2. you say includes.js, but it is actually a PHP file.  3.  Why you using `WP_CONTENT_DIR` when you should be using `ABSPATH`?  Or better yet:  `plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )` 4. You are using `$hook` variable that could very well be undefined, and return out of `includes.php` and not load the .js file needed for the function. 5. If you are registering the script with `wp_register_script`, `wp_enqueue_script` should only have the tag name of the script (1st parameter). 6. There is no `candidates_gen_js` function defined.

Comment: thankyou solomon for replying.1. yes 'includes' is a php file. 2. as per the examples i used WP_CONTENT_DIR for including file. now i changed it with 'include plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )."includes.php";' 3. as per your suggestion i changed wp_enqueue_script('1st parameter') 4. candidates_gen_js is define its not visible in code right now.

Comment: can you please elaborate more how i should call to my js files so that it works

Comment: Please see my answer below.  I believe your issue, however, is related to the output of your html via PHP.  Scroll down, in answer, to see how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In wordpress, `wp_enqueue_script` gets used to output the script to the page.  `wp_register_script` gets used if you need to register the script so that it can be used anywhere you need it to be used (on any page).

If you need the script to be used elsewhere, than you should register it first, than enqueue it afterwards anywhere you need it.

If you register the script first, than all you need to do is call the first parameter that you gave it when you registered the script with `wp_register_script` and you would use that in the `wp_enqueue_script` part.

Example:

```
// Register script, dependant on jQuery
wp_register_script('can_list',plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'cand.js', array('jquery'));
// Enqueue the Script for output onto page:
wp_enqueue_script('can_list');
```

Than you will be able to use:  `wp_enqueue_script('can_list');` anywhere else you need it to load at.

If you only need to output that script in that spot only, than simple do this:

```
// Script output on page, loading jQuery first.
wp_enqueue_script('can_list',plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'cand.js', array('jquery'));
```

Let me know if you need any further information on this.

You would put these in a function that would be called on either hook:
`admin_enqueue_scripts` (if needed in the admin section), and/or `wp_enqueue_scripts` (if needed on the front-end section).

Honestly, I think your issue is more related to the echo of your html and PHP for the `onclick` handler of `$item['id']`.

For outputting PHP, should use `print` or `echo`.  I prefer using `echo` personally as I feel it is better for performance of site.  Ofcourse, there are millions of other methods to output html, etc., but those are the 2 used most often and important for your situation.

For example:

`<a href="#" onclick ="show_details('.$item['id'].');" >Click here </a>'`

should be this:

`<?php echo '<a href="#" onclick="show_details('.$item['id'].');">Click here</a>'; ?>`

or this

`<a href="#" onclick="show_details(<?php echo $item['id']; ?>);">Click here</a>`

Comment: thankyou for giving such elaborated explanation, but i am not able to include my js file. followed is my code now in includes.php file  ::::    <?php
function candidates_gen_js($hook) {
 
 if( $hook != 'candidate_cv_listing.php' ) 
  return;
 // core
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
 
 // registering my js file
 
 wp_enqueue_script('can_list',plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'cand.js', array('jquery'));
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'candidates_gen_js');


?> i am not getting what exactly i am doing wrong, all i need to call my  js function and then open the result in fancybox in admin end

Comment: ok, i followed :: http://www.sitepoint.com/using-wp_list_table-to-create-wordpress-admin-tables/ to create a table for my candiadate list. and inorder to have a click here link ::  i am using switch statement as example explains. and return like this :: case 'view_data':
   return  '<a href="#"  onclick ="show_details('.$item['id'].');" >Click here </a>';
   break;

Comment: my hard luck, i tried both ways of <a href> as per suggestion but still it is not calling my js function :(

Comment: Also, in your function, right before you return out of it on the call for `$hook`, check the result of what `$hook` is being set at by simply adding this bit of code at the very top of the function before returning out of it:  `var_dump($hook);`  It will than output the value of what `$hook` is on the page (at the very top).  Be sure that this is the same as you are checking against, should output:  `candidate_cv_listing.php` for that admin page that you need the js file on.  If it doesn't output that value, than change your if statement to check for whatever it outputs on that page.

Comment: Thank you soo much for all your support and giving me value able information, i checked $hook, it was null that's why code was not working now i commented if condition. and its working fine :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Furthermore, it is important to register a script using `wp_register_script` if another script is dependant on it, for example, if you have `app.js` that is needed to load after `can_list.js`, than you would register the script, than plug in the name you gave it (`can_list`) into the `wp_enqueue_script` function for the `app.js` file.  Example:  `wp_enqueue_script('app_js',plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'app.js', array('jquery', 'can_list'));`  As long as `can_list` is registered with `wp_register_script` it will load up `jquery` and `can_list` first, than `app.js`.

Comment: thanks for information, its a great learning for the day :). have a good day

Comment: Hi solomon, i want to ask you about sql injection. How can i restrict user from entering sql injection elements into the form.

Comment: Please open another question if you want answer to that.  Thank you :)